# Completion of space of piecewise-smooth curves under $H^2$ norm

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I'm currently working in a setting where Sobolev spaces of the form $H^2(I, \mathbb{R}^n)$ appear, where $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a closed interval. We construct such a set by considering the space $C^{\infty}(I, \mathbb{R}^n)$ of smooth functions from $I$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and then completing it with respect to the sobolev norm $\| \cdot\|_{H^2}$. We find that $H^2(I, \mathbb{R}^n)$ is, in fact, a Hilbert space, and it is a subset of $C^1(I, \mathbb{R}^n)$.

I'm wondering what happens if instead we complete the space $C^{\infty}_p(I, \mathbb{R}^n)$ of piecewise-smooth functions with respect to the $H^2$ norm (let's call this completion $H^2_p(I, \mathbb{R}^n)$). It's clear that $H^2_p(I, \mathbb{R}^n)$ is a Banach space by construction, and, as far as I can tell, the inner product on $H^2$ is also an inner product on $H^2_p$, making it a Hilbert space. I suspect that the inclusion $H^2_p(I, \mathbb{R}^n) \subset C^1_p(I, \mathbb{R}^n)$ will hold as well. Is this correct?

**Edit:** I will say that $f \in C^{\infty}_p(I, \mathbb{R}^n)$ if and only if there exists a finite collection of open intervals $\{I_i\}$ such that the corresponding collection of closed intervals $\{\bar{I_i}\}$ is a partition of $I$, and the restrictions $f \vert_{I_i}$ are smooth.

Comment: How do you define piecewise smooth ?

Comment: @LL3.14 I've added an edit to explain what I mean by piecewise smooth.

Comment: Ok, but then the problem is that $H^2$ functions are $C^1$, while $C^\infty_p$ contains discontinuous functions ... so their $H^2$ norm is not even always well-defined. In particular, $H^2$ is not a scalar product on $H^2_p$.

Comment: @LL3.14 Why would the norm not be well-defined? Integrals do not care about finite quantities of discontinuities, so we could always extend the norm as $\|f\|^2 = \sum_{j=0}^2 \int_I \| D^{(j)} f(t)\|^2 dt :=\sum_{i} \sum_{j=0}^2 \int_{I_i} \| D^{(j)} f(t)\|^2 dt$, where $D$ is the differential operator (and $D^{(2)}f$ is a weak derivative).

Comment: They care! When you take the weak derivative of a function with a discontinuity, it gives a Dirac delta ...

Comment: @LL3.14 Okay, but surely the norm defined in my previous comment (but with $D^{(2)} f$ as the normal second derivative of $f$) is well-defined on $C_p^{\infty}(I, \mathbb{R}^n)$. So the completion of $C_p^{\infty}(I, \mathbb{R}^n)$ under this norm must give *some* Banach space, even if the normal notion of weak derivative fails there, no?

Comment: No, the $H^2$ is not well defined on $C^\infty_p$. The unit step function is in $C^\infty_p$ but it's weak derivative is not in $H^2$ as it is a Dirac delta. The main problem in your sum formula is that it does not apply when $Df$ is a general distribution such as a measure, which is what happens when you take weak derivatives

Comment: @LL3.14 I believe there's a misunderstanding. I'm saying to *define* a norm on $C_p^{\infty}$ by $\|f\|^2 = \sum_{i} \sum_{j=1}^2 \int_{I_i} \|D^{(j)}f(t)\|dt$, where $D^{(j)} f$ is the normal derivative of $f$ (not weak) and $\{I_i\}$ is the collection of subintervals on which $f$ is smooth. The completion of $C^{\infty}_p$ with respect to this norm will give some Banach space, which I call $H^2_p$.

Comment: But the intervals depend on the functions. Does such a definition defines a norm?